# Misunderstanding integer valued random variable

Tags: probability

I've seen an exercise where I'm supposed to show that for an integer valued random variable $X$ then $ \forall m \in \mathbb{N} $ we  have $\sum_{n \geq 1} P(n < X \leq n+m) = m$ .

I wanted to verify it for $m=1$ and it seems to fails already, unless I'm not understanding the problem, indeed for $m=1$ we get : 
$\sum_{n \geq 1} P(n < X \leq n+m) = \sum_{n \geq 1} P( n < X \leq n+1) = \sum_{ n \geq 1} P(X=n+1)=P(X>1) $

I don't see why it should be equal to $1$ unless the values of $X$ was the integer $2,3,\cdots$ 
Now assumes I wanted to do some induction :
$\sum_{n \geq 1} P(n < X \leq n+m+1) = \\ \sum_{n \geq 1} P(n < X \leq n+m) + P(X=n+m+1) = m + \sum_{n \geq 1} P(X=n+m+1) $  
So to me this equality seems correct if $ \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$ we have: $P(X > m+1) =\sum_{n \geq 1} P(X=n+m+1) = 1 $
However I don't see why it should be true  ... (this is wrong I guess)
Maybe I'm not understanding what "integer valued random variable" means but I thought it meant that it takes values in $\mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{N}$ if by some abuse they forgot to mention non-negative)...
Thanks !

Comment: You are right, in general it fails for $m=1$.  I think the sum should be $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ (where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers) rather than $\sum_{n \geq 1}$.

Comment: You are right in this case $ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} P(X=n+m) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} P(X=n) = 1$ and it works...so I guess there was a typo in this exercise!

Comment: You do not need $X$ to take integer values, but you do need $n$ and $m$ to be integers.  What you are doing is adding up $m$ times the probability of each half-open unit interval $(n,n+1]$